# Using routing key to communicate services

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue, soa, esb, microservices

Take the following sample requirement:

> **Service A** does some work. That work is done periodically and no one asks **Service A** to do it. It's done automatically.
>
> **Service B** needs to query data produced by **Service A**. **Service A** resides in a different server than **Service B**.

That is, **Service B** won't be able to get data if **Service A** doesn't provide some way of asking it for the data.

I want to require **Service A** data *the SOA way* using *RabbitMQ*: when **Service B** requires some data, it sends a message to a given exchange and its written to some queue. Then, **Service A** processes the message and publishes the *answer* to some other exchange. Finally, **Service B** listens the *answer message* and the cycle ends.

### My question

I need some way to both publish and consume messages identified by the operation that requested data to **Service A**, and I also need that each started operation could be identified by an *unique identifier*.

My question is about how to publish a message and be able to receive an answer for a particular invocation of an operation.

I just want to validate that RabbitMQ *routing keys* are the answer to this requirement. For example, **Service A** sends a message with a routing key `072e6ee1-6046-4c3b-bade-9077c863637b`. There's a consumer in **Service B** which consumes any message ignoring the routing key, but once it produces a result, it does publishing a message to an exchange with the same routing key . Therefore, **Service A** receives message because it's bound to the whole routing key.

Is it a possible right usage of *routing keys*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, RabbitMQ already provides a solution to solve my scenario: [Remote Procedure Calls tutorial](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-python.html).

At the end of the day, a message can have **correlation id** and a **reply to** fields:

- **Correlation id**. An arbitrary value used to uniquely-identify an operation across many exchanges/queues.
- **Reply to**. An arbitrary `string` to define on which exchange or queue you want to put the result of a given operation. The target exchange/queue will be the *callback* information that will be received by the operation.

Thus, **Service A** sends a message to a given exchange with a **correlation id** and a **reply to** value. It gets subscribed to **reply to** exchange. When **Service B** processes the message it publishes a message to the *reply to exchange* and **Service A** receives the whole result.

BTW, I still have some concerns about this model, because you need to receive callback messages from other operations while you wait for the result, and whenever you consume a message that's not marked with desired **correlation id**, you simply don't process it and you wait for the next one, and so on, until you get what you want.

Maybe it might be a good idea that *callback messages* would be queued [with a *time-to-live*](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html) so if who started an operation isn't waiting for the callback anymore, a given callback message would be automatically dropped.

Another approach would be throwing the callback information as a document or record in a SQL/NoSQL database, and poll the database with an indexed query *by callback identifier*...

If I find some other approach using RabbitMQ I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't seem to be the correct way to use routing keys, if I understand you correctly. Routing keys tend to be used to define an operation, eg 'do-this' or 'do-that' - I wouldn't expect them to contain keys, unless those keys were a limited set that defined how the system operates. The Ids that you mention (they seem to be correlation Ids, so that you can match a received response to an outbound request, asynchronously) would be contained in the body of the message. So, you have the following setup:

1. Service B -> send message to exchange with routing key 'process-data'. The message contains the Id in its body.
2. Service A listens to messages on Queue A, which is is bound to the exchange with binding key 'process-data'. It then dequeue's Service B's message, whose body contains the Id
3. Service A performs processing
4. Service A -> send message to exchange with routing key 'data-processed'. The message contains the original Id in its body.
5. Service B listens to messages on Queue B, which is is bound to the exchange with binding key 'data-processed'. It then dequeue's Service A's message, whose body contains the Id

Comment: Hey! Thank you for your answer. My concern is that in the fith step, how does Service B receives the message? Would it need to consume all messages and filter them by `Id` and *ACK* the message that has the desired `Id`? That's the reason behind thinking about routing keys, because I would be able to receive the message without wasting a lot of resources receiving messages that I don't want to receive.

Comment: I'm still looking for the best solution and I've found that you can use message headers for that matter too. Maybe is this the solution? Message headers instead of routing keys

Comment: See my own answer, I believe that this should be a good solution, isn't it?

Comment: Uhm after testing my found solution, it seems like consumers can't filter by message headers. It's just aimed to do so when you configure a headers exchange bindings...

Comment: I found the RMQ help pages useful. You may want to look at Topic exchange: https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-five-python.html

Comment: Do you mean using topic exchange wildcards? `results:3839389`? The problem with that is I would create tons of exchange for a single use...

Comment: I've found another tutorial, https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-python.html

Comment: Thank you for your effort. Finally I've selected my own answer as the right one. I've already implemented an use case this way and it works flawlessly